# Find out what's trying to allocate too much ram

Tags: laravel

I'm turning to the community because I don't know what to do, my backend is running on Laravel 6, and since more than a month I see a new error message appearing in my logs and on slack (I've configured exception reporting on slack). I can't figure out what's causing the allocation of so much memory.

Below is the error message in question:

```
[2020-03-25 16:40:56] production.ERROR: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 2859008 bytes) {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException(code: 1): Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 2859008 bytes) at /var/www/site/project/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php:365)
```

I tried to test all the features of my project but I can't trigger this error message. I'd like to point out that I've never had this error in a local environment.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Hi Youss, I'm afraid we don't have enough information here to give you a proper answer. Sometimes reading too much data from the database ('eager loading' too much data) can be a problem. If this is the issue you might need to paginate your data/pages.

Comment: just a hunch it could be the log file on the server. Check the directory for large files.

Comment: @Flame Good idea, I just tested it, but I still have the exception that goes up

Comment: @JiFus Precisely all my results are paginated, I only wish I had a clue where it could come from but I don't have any.

Comment: @Youss Did you check `http-foundation/Response.php:365`? There should probably be a start there? Maybe the response you're trying to send is too big like I said. Furthermore there should be a stacktrace of the reset of the error right? If you know through what classes your code went, you might also see where you could be accumulating a lot of data.